# Code Re-use: HTML 5 Equivalent of Server Side Includes/ASP.NET Master Pages/User Controls

Tags: html

Someone recently asked me if there was a way in HTML 5 to re-use sections of a page across multiple pages without typing the entire text out.

Perhaps he meant the client-side HTML-equivalent of server side technologies such as the Server Side Includes (SSI) and ASP.NET Master Pages and User Controls.

Even though I am new to HTML 5 and I am by no means a seasoned Web developer, the question sounded preposterous to me as re-using elements of mark-up is a job of the server which prepares the response; HTML simply provides a syntax for the mark-up.

But then, since I don't know much I was wondering if there was in fact such an HTML 5 equivalent and that the question wasn't all that unseemly as I thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Re-using code is not something that the client-side can do without help from a program. Dreamweaver is one in particular that will allow you to make a template that can be used across multiple pages. It basically acts as a pre-processor for your html.

There are ways to display the same block of code in several locations using javascript or jquery but that's not built in to html5.